# Amazon online assessment coding question to find nth Geometric Progression

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, double

Given the 2nd and 3rd term of a Geometric Progression. Find the nth term of it and round it off up to 3 decimal places.

we have to complete the following function:

```
char* nthTerm(double input1, double input2, int input3) {
    //your code here
}
```

```
input1 = 2nd term and input2 = 3rd term and both are between -2 to 2.
input3 = nth term to find and can be up to 100.
```

I was unable to convert the result from double to an array of char in the time limits. The test was on [Mettl](http:////https://mettl.com/) platform and I think I was unable to use to_string(), stringstream, etc. Although pow() function working fine.

```
e.g input1 = 1, input2 = 2, input3 = 4
  output = 4.0
```

Please, someone, help on how to solve this problem.

My approach but getting compilation error and wrong verdicts:

```
    double r = input2/input1;
    double a = input1/r;
    double ans = a * (double)pow(r, (double)(input3-1));
    char *result = new char[1000];
    // from here i tried so many thing like i used to_string, 
    // setprecision, maps, etc. But getting errors only.
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include your attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.

Comment: Note that rounding to 3 decimal places is easily done with the built-in `round` function.  Converting to a full-length array is done with the formatting functions, the same ones you use when formatting output.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should first include what you tried as part of the question. Anyway, in order to convert a double value to char pointer, first you can use sprintf to convert it into a char array and then simply convert the result to char pointer. Example code below :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char charray[200];
    double num = 121.14;
    sprintf(charray, "%2.3f", num);
    char* c = &charray[0];
    printf("%s", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks [@user2125722](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2125722/user2125722), I forgot the usage of this function during the test and now understand it properly and I think this is the right way of conversion. But one more issue here is how to calculate big values, for e.g, if n = 100, 2nd term = 1 and 3rd term = 2. Then the result will be very large, I guess, how to handle that?

Comment: @ChakshuJain For calculating huge exponentials, you should perform modular exponentiation and then convert